# Invisible CSS comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, comments

I have recently begun the practice of using <%# Ruby on Rails comments %> in my html.erb files, as these do not display in the source code that is then viewable by a user.

Is there a way of adding comments to .css files that keeps them private from the eyes of devilish onlookers?

Comment: Why are you commenting your css? If you're pushing unminified css to the production - you're-doin-it-wrong.

Comment: Good point Eimantas, thanks for that reminder. I assume it is common then to have both an unminified and a minified version of each stylesheet, and each time there's a change we just reminify and replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eimantas already said: it's not a good practice to send unminified version of JS/CSS files in production (you will get bad mark in YSlow for that).

There is a nice gem: http://github.com/thumblemonks/smurf

And it works like a charm: all you need is to mention it in your gem file (Rails 3)

```
gem "smurf"
```

and that's it! Well, that's it if you use :cache => ... in your stylesheet_link_tag:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "foo", "bar", :cache => "public.css"
```

It intercepts standard Rails behavior that saves concatenated files to disk and compress them just before.

And to mention the obvious - it will compress the file only in production mode as the :cache option works only if cacheing is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The same as for HTML — strip them before delivery to the client (either server side, or before uploading).

You may want to link a minification tool (e.g. [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)) into your build/publication process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) to author your stylesheets, it has a `//` comment syntax that is not emitted in the output CSS. (I recommend you use it via [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), especially if you're using Rails).

Sass has a syntax variant called SCSS, which is fully CSS compatible if you don't love the indented structure of Sass.